# Get 'default' FROM address if no FROM address is given .NET.Mail

Tags: c#, email, smtp

After a few hours of MAIL research (many many questions on it) I ended up asking the question myself since I can't find an answer that completely answers mine.

For one of my applications I am building a Mailing class library with `System.Net.Mail` that handles outgoing mails through SMTP. The FROM address is an optional parameter, if it is not given then the code should set/handle the FROM address.

Since not all mail clients are the same I want to build something that get's the right FROM address.

After some research I found out that I can use the `UserPrincipal.Current.EmailAddress` to accomplish this but I found out that the EmailAddress value is not always there in the Active Directory.

The question is, is there a way to always get the FROM address or is this undo-able? Or should I just limit it to the most used used mail clients like outlook and gmail?

Comment: Realistically you cannot tell what is the "correct" email address, for example, you could scour my laptop all you like, I dont run any email apps on it. But i have a number of email addresses, and one which would be my preferred, but only I know which that is.  AD looks up tend to work best when a local exchange server is in use, however, this is not always the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most SMTP servers that are set up for production use don't allow "from spoofing".  In other words, they require the FROM address to be the one used to log in to SMTP.  While there's nothing in the SMTP spec that requires that practice, the presence of spammers does.

Getting the email address from ActiveDirectory can also be derived if it is not explicitly set.  The ActiveDirectory is set up within a domain, so the email address would be the `userId + '@' + activeDirectoryDomain`.  The place where this becomes a problem is if you are using claims based authentication from third parties, and the third party doesn't populate the email claim.  For example, Facebook and Google authentication provide an email address while Twitter authentication does not.

In all cases, there should be a system default email address.  You'll have to coordinate with the people who manage the SMTP service, but they can set up a "no-reply" email address for outgoing only email.  That would be your final option if you can't derive it any other way.

Comment: Great explanation! Makes it much clearer. I will probably just make the FROM address non optional. Thank you.